# How do I manage state of an imported component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and have a file that has multiple components and I'm trying to split them into separate component files. However, when I move them into different files, my onChange stops working. Here is what I'm currently trying:

ParamSelection file:

```
function ParamSelection() {
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
return (
<div className={styles.paramSelection}>
        <StartDate
            onChange={(date) => {setStartDate({date})}}
        />
        </div>
);
};
```

StartDate file:

```
function StartDate() {
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();

return (
    <Flatpickr
            className={styles.dateSelection}
            placeholder="Select Start Date and Time"
            options={{
                enableTime: true,
                enableSeconds: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-dTH:i:S",
                time_24hr: true,
                position: "below",
                minuteIncrement: 1,
                secondIncrement: 1,
                mode: "single",
                static: true
            }}
            onChange={(date) => {setStartDate({date})}}
            />
);
};

export default StartDate;
```

When I run this, the startDate state value doesn't get updated so any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Your `StartDate` _ignores_ the `onChange` you're passing into it, and instead creates its own, so: where should that state live? In `StartDate` or in `ParamSelection`? (also note that you don't need curly brackets for one-liner arrow functions. and that you're currently passing the date as an object with the key `date` and then its value, so it feels like you want `(date) => setStartDate(date)` instead, in addition to fixing which component "owns" this state)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I didn't know that about that brackets thank you. The state should live in ParamSelection

Comment: Then remove that state variable from StartDate, and [add a `props` function argument](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#step-2-read-props-inside-the-child-component), so it can actually _get_ its own properties =)

Answer (score 1):

Just simply take props from ParamSelection and make sure in that page you should have defined state and onChange properly. and then after in StartDate you have to take onChange as a props and give it to Flatpickr like that.

```
function StartDate({ onChange }) {

return (
    <Flatpickr
            className={styles.dateSelection}
            placeholder="Select Start Date and Time"
            options={{
                enableTime: true,
                enableSeconds: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-dTH:i:S",
                time_24hr: true,
                position: "below",
                minuteIncrement: 1,
                secondIncrement: 1,
                mode: "single",
                static: true
            }}
            onChange={onChange}}
            />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass the state from parent and get the updated onChange value, below is the working example of passing state from parent this, You can replace input with your component:

```
function StartDate({ state, setState }) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        placeholder="Select Start Date and Time"
        options={{
          enableTime: true,
          enableSeconds: true,
          dateFormat: "Y-m-dTH:i:S",
          time_24hr: true,
          position: "below",
          minuteIncrement: 1,
          secondIncrement: 1,
          mode: "single",
          static: true,
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
        value={state}
      />
      <br />
      This is my state value: {state}
    </>
  );
}

export default StartDate;
```

---

```
import { useState } from "react";
import StartDate from "./StartDate";

export function Test() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <StartDate state={startDate} setState={setStartDate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```